# Not able to understand why this error is coming,

Tags: python-3.x, collections, nltk, tokenize, iterable

```
   '''import collections
try:
        collectionsAbc = collections.abc
        except AttributeError:`enter code here`
        collectionsAbc = collections
        from inltk.inltk import tokenize
        from collections.abc import Iterable
        hindi_text = """प्राचीन काल में विक्रमादित्य नाम के एक आदर्श राजा हुआ करते थे।
        अपने साहस, पराक्रम और शौर्य के लिए  राजा विक्रम मशहूर थे। ऐसा भी कहा जाता है कि राजा विक्रम अपनी 
         प्राजा के जीवन के दुख दर्द जानने के लिए रात्री के पहर में भेष बदल कर नगर में घूमते थे।"""

          # tokenize(input text, language code)
## Heading ##tokenize(hindi_text, "hi")'''
```

this code is giving import error: cannot import name 'Iterable' from 'collections' (C:\Users\123\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\collections_*init*_.py)

Answer (score 0):

This is the line that's giving you the error; what follows does not matter, Python never gets to it:

```
from collections.abc import Iterable
```

Since this import should have succeeded, there are two possible explanations.  Either your Python installation is corrupted, and your module is broken; or the code you are running is not what you show here.

In fact you are *definitely* not running the code that you show here, because your sample is pretty garbled; it is several edits away from being valid Python. So create another script and make this import the first line of code; if it succeeds, the problem is with the statements that appear earlier in your actual script. If it still does not succeed, reinstall Python.